# What the mean "forceFit : true" at jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jqgrid, properties

What the mean attribute"forceFit : true" at jqgrid, for what?
Thanks. =)

Comment: So basically your're to lazy to look it up in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) and rather want someone there to read the docs for you?

Comment: im sorry,I've read the documentation,but I'm not people from england or american,and I do not understand english language.i can write english language because google translater,and I understand the language I use chaotic.Im only question for people who understands.not tell you to read the documentation.Thanks

Comment: If you cannot understand the English languge, then why do you ask questions on an English-speaking website? If you have a good translator, why don't you translate the documentation?

Comment: I've translate with google translater, but the language I want to be messed up. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple google [search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=forceFit%20jqgrid#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=forceFit%2bjqgrid&pbx=1&oq=forceFit%2bjqgrid&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3463l3817l0l4168l2l2l0l0l0l0l172l326l0.2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a24a3d35bf32fb78&biw=1440&bih=775) found http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2h30rdx62.htm

> added property forceFit (boolean, default false) When set to true and
>   resizing the width of a column, the adjacent column (to the right)
>   resizes so that the overall grid width is maintained (e.g., reducing
>   the width of column 2 by 30px increases the size of column 3 by 30px).
>   In this case there is no horizontal scrolbar. Note: this option is not
>   compatible with shrinkToFit option - i.e if shrinkToFit is set to
>   false, forceFit is ignored.